# How to force CentOS yum to use a later version of a package dependency already installed (php-common as a dependency of php-xml)

Tags: yum, installation, php

It would appear that the version I have of `php-common-5.2.10-1.el5.centos` is newer than the one being asked for as a dependency of `php-xml` when I try to install `php-xml` using `yum install php-xml`. The dependent package asked for is `php-common = 5.1.6-34.el5_8` as shown by `rpm -qa |grep php`.

So how would I force php-xml to use the later verion I already have?

(This seems to be the root cause of the problem in related SF question: [php-xml install complains of dependency php-common but this is already installed (CentOS)](https://serverfault.com/questions/391772/php-xml-install-complains-of-dependency-php-common-but-this-is-already-installed) )

**Update**

output of:

- `yum repolist`
- `rpm -qi php-common`

(as requested by @ewwhite )is as follows:

```
[root@dtsrvishvt2 ~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * extras: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * updates: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
Reducing CentOS-5 Testing to included packages only
Finished
repo id                          repo name                                status
base                             CentOS-5 - Base                          2,725
c5-testing                       CentOS-5 Testing                          0+71
extras                           CentOS-5 - Extras                          280
updates                          CentOS-5 - Updates                         379
repolist: 3,384
[root@dtsrvishvt2 ~]#





[root@dtsrvishvt2 ~]# rpm -qi php-common
Name        : php-common                   Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 5.2.10                            Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 1.el5.centos                  Build Date: Fri 13 Nov 2009 04:36:29 PM GMT
Install Date: Tue 13 Jul 2010 11:33:44 AM GMT      Build Host: builder10.centos.org
Group       : Development/Languages         Source RPM: php-5.2.10-1.el5.centos.src.rpm
Size        : 668395                           License: PHP
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Fri 22 Jan 2010 03:22:25 PM GMT, Key ID 5c37c0b17203f491
URL         : http://www.php.net/
Summary     : Common files for PHP
Description :
The php-common package contains files used by both the php
package and the php-cli package.
[root@dtsrvishvt2 ~]#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you provide the output of the following commands?

- `yum repolist`
- `rpm -qi php-common`

The current version of php-common for your CentOS 5 system is `php-common-5.1.6-34.el5_8`. Your dependency issue stems from the presence of a newer version of php-common (5.2.10-1.el5.centos) than what is available in the standard CentOS repository. The `yum repolist` command will help us understand where you're pulling your packages from. The `rpm -qi php-common` will show us where the currently installed package actually came from.

My guess is that the system was moved to PHP 5.2 using another repo, or maybe by a manual package installation. This has been [documented online](http://portalbuilders.pro/PBblog/centos-5-upgrading-php-to-version-5-2/) with the use of the CentOS Testing repository. If your php-common package was a one-off installation, then you should be able to grab the relevant php packages... but this depends on your repolist output...

Comment: +1 @ewwhite thanks for your input, I've updated the question with the output that you suggested

Comment: The problem is the C5-testing repository. The PHP 5.2 packages have been [removed from the Centos5-Testing](http://osdir.com/ml/centos/2012-03/msg00456.html) repo (security reasons). You can probably remove the repo and the php package, going back to 5.1, or try to find a way to move to php 5.3.

Comment: +1 @ewwhite for your comment - which seals your answer as the accepted - thanks. In summary I should try to move to php 5.3. Thanks.

Comment: Full steps on how to upgrade CentOS 5.4 to PHP-5.3 are detailed here (working as of May 2012 - repos and paths exist and work): http://serverfault.com/questions/391772/php-xml-install-complains-of-dependency-php-common-but-this-is-already-installed/392168#392168

Answer (score 2):

You can't, yum won't let you. The authors of php-xml specifically want a version of php-common that matches theirs.

Your choices are:

1. Find a newer version of the php-xml rpm
2. Downgrade php-common to version `5.2.10-1.el5.centos`
3. Use `rpm -i --nodeps` to perform an unsafe install that may not work right (since you are not installing any dependencies).
4. Rebuild the php-xml rpm, changing the version of php-commons that it depends on

I strongly recommend one of the first two, since they are easiest and have the best chance of working correctly.

Comment: +1 @Konstantin Naryshkin: "Find a newer version of the php-xml rpm" - this corroborates with the accepted answer to upgrade to php 5.3: presumably 5.3 uses a later version of php-xml.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use php-commons version 5.2* as it has been removed due to a security issue. The only option left is to upgrade to PHP 5.3.  It took me about 4 hours to find this information online so hopefully this will help someone else.